Ubuntu in Dell Inspiron I15-5547?
Is it possible to install Ubuntu in a Laptop Dell Inspiron I15-5547? It has touch screen and I'm afraid there's no support in Ubuntu for that. Thanks

Ubuntu supports most touch screen devices out of the box!
Just flash Ubuntu 24.04 to a USB drive, and boot from the USB drive to test if everything works.
If somehow the touch does not work, ask a new question.

Thank you @Archisman Panigrahi!!!

You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark if it worked for you
